# Easyadmin is not recognizing boolean type

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.7, symfony2-easyadmin

I am trying to implement a backend using easyadmin, I think its a great idea and I love the implementation... so far is going well, but I have a little problem, I want to show in the form a boolean field, for ex: 'published', my configuration looks like this:

```
Blog:
    label: 'Posts list'
    class: MyCompany\MyBundle\Entity\Post
    list:
        fields: ['title', 'published']
    new:
        fields: 
          - 'title'
          - 'summary'
          - 'body'
          - { property: 'published', type: 'boolean' }
```

When I run this code, I get the error:

> Could not load type "boolean"

This is how I define the field in the Entity:

```
/**
 * 
 * @ORM\Column(name="published", type="boolean", length=1)
 */
protected $published = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been a while since this question's posted, but for anyone still getting this error, in easyadmin documentation (https://github.com/javiereguiluz/EasyAdminBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/book/4-edit-new-configuration.md) it is specified which types we need to use for each scenario (list, edit views). 
In your question (edit scenario) so far the only workaround is to use "checkbox"as type in config.yml. Edit view only accepts Symfony Form Types (http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types.html).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15438062)

Comment: Sorry, this is the useful text from the link "type (optional): the Symfony Form type used to render this field. You can use the short type name (e.g. email) instead of its fully qualified class name (e.g. Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType) even if your application runs on Symfony 3 (the needed conversion is done internally by the bundle).The allowed values are:
Any of the Symfony Form types.
Any of the custom EasyAdmin form types: easyadmin_autocomplete (they are explained later in this chapter)."

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to specify type in configuration yml file. It will take automatically from entity.

Comment: This works only if entity has that property declared explicitly